# Does it mean that men are more likely to harass people or is it saying that men harassing men is more common than women harassing women?

Tags: reading

[Link to the source where this is found](http://www.gvsu.edu/women_cen/sexual-harassment--82.htm)

> **Men are more likely than women to harass**.
>
> Both male and female students are more likely to
> be harassed by a man than by a woman. Half of
> male students and almost one-third of female
> students admit that they sexually harassed
> someone in college, and about one-fifth of male
> students admit that they harassed someone often
> or occasionally. Although equal proportions of
> male and female students say that they harassed a
> student of the other gender, male students are
> more likely to admit to harassing other male
> students. Almost one-quarter of male harassers
> admit to harassing male students, compared to
> one-tenth of female harassers who admit to
> harassing female students.

My question is: The first part of the paragraph seems to say that men are more likely to harass people, but the later portion of it says that men harassing men is more common than women harassing women. What is the paragraph actually trying to say? Can someone help me calrify this please? Thanks.

Comment: Its saying that men are dirty rotten scoundrels. :) As a whole, it is saying men are overall more likely to do this. In both cases men are more likely to harass.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. For example, men harrassing men will not be the same quantity as men harrassing men or women.

Comment: To be precise, it says that male students are more like "to admit" to harassing other students.

Comment: What is the specific sentence or phrase in the passage that is not understood?

Comment: @TRomano - good point about admitting to it.Had to upvote. So, it could be saying that women are less likely to admit to harassing other people. Those sneaky fibbers. :)

Comment: With 50% of guys fessing up, I think "ogling" must be included in the contemporary definition of "non-contact" sexual harassment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *The first part of the paragraph seems to say that men are more likely to harass people...*

That's true. It does:

> Half of male students and almost one-third of female students admit that they sexually harassed someone in college.

---

> *...but the later portion of it says that men harassing men is more common than women harassing women*

Yup, it says that, too:

> Almost one-quarter of male harassers admit to harassing male students, compared to one-tenth of female harassers who admit to harassing female students

---

> *What is the paragraph actually trying to say?*

The paragraph is summarizing the results of a study on harassment. Whoever did the study collected a lot of data, and several conclusions could be drawn from that data. This kind of writing can often be found when an author is trying to summarize the conclusions of an in-depth study in a few short paragraphs. In an academic settings, you'll often see this style of writing in conference procedings or journals, where it will often be accompanied by tables or graphs with the data. For example, see the various graphs on the pages of [this report](http://www.aauw.org/files/2013/02/drawing-the-line-sexual-harassment-on-campus.pdf), which is based on the same study. What you call "the first part of the paragraph" is based on Figure 6, found on page 23:

[image]

(In the excerpt you quote, 51% is summarized as *"half of"*, and 31% is expressed as *"almost one-third of"*.)

Comment: Very well explained